# in Python, how to best read lines from a child and grandchild, including last incomplete line?

Tags: python

In Python,  I can spawn a child and get a file descriptor of its output like this:

```
pid, out = pty.fork()
if pid:
```

now I want to read lines from child output until it dies (which I can check with a non-blocking `waitpid(pid)`).

I would like to do this:

```
    f = os.fdopen(out)
```

and now

```
    for line in f:
```

or

```
    while True:
        f.readline()
```

But there are at least two problems here:
1.  Suppose the child dies while emitting the last line.  Now `for` and `readline` will throw an exception, and how can I read the incomplete line from inside the exception handler?

2. If the child spawns a grand-child, and then dies, then again `for` and `readline` will throw an exception immediately.  I want to wait for a while for the output from the grandchild.

The alternative, is to do

```
    while True:
        (rSet, _, _) = select.select([out], [], [], <some seconds>)
        if rSet:
            buf = os.read(out, <some length>)
            if buf:
                #process it, assembling lines
            else:
                #check if child dead, if so, bail out
```

But that is rather cumbersome, requiring me to laboriously assemble lines by myself.

Is this the best way, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by '\n', a string containing only a single newline.

Comment: Yes I read this, but it seems that this means, the end of the real file.  How does `f.readline()` know the child died and won't output anymore?  `f.readline()` does not know anything about the child process, does it?

Comment: @MarkGaleck I'm pretty sure the file doesn't "end" until the child process dies. You can try testing this at least, for child process healthy death and kill -9.

Comment: @MarkGaleck `readline` knows nothing of the child process. Usually, when a process ends, the OS will close any file descriptors left open by that process, thus emitting [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Comment: Yes thank you I checked, `readline` works, and also `for line in f` works, by exception.  But both don't work when the child dies while emitting a line.  How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the pipe from the child process is going to get closed, and you're going to get an IOError when trying to read from it.

EDIT (Following your edit): The OS buffers the output in the pipe, so you're supposed to get everything it wrote into it (up to a point where it overflows, ofcourse)

Comment: yes I checked thank you, indeed I also get an exception from `newline`.  But please explain how am I supposed to get that last incomplete line??  Where is it "buffered"?

Comment: The OS is bufferring it, so reading it should be ok. Only case I can think of with the last line getting cut is if you kill it with -9 (and not some ordinary signal) and it was in mid-writing.

Comment: BTW checked it too and I'm getting "input/output error", though I was expecting "broken pipe". Oh well...